# Problem with Angular button naming based on naming array

Tags: angular, typescript, button

I am having problems with button naming in an Angular SPA component that I am creating.

Context - I have a page that displays a data table and I have a 'Select' control that allows the user to select columns to be hidden in the table. When the user selects a column that column is hidden and a corresponding button is displayed with the column name as the button text. The user is allowed to select multiple columns to hide with the corresponding button being created. My issue is that the buttons are being named after the last column name selected.

Design - I've created an array to hold the column information.

component html--

```
<div *ngFor="let column of columns">
<button class="actionbutton" id="{{columnId}}" (click)="showColumn(selectedColumn)">{{columnName}}</button></div>
```

component .ts file

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.columnArray.length; i++) {
this.columnId = this.columnArray[i];
this.columnId = this.columnId.replace(' ', '-') + '-' + i;

this.columnName = this.columnArray.splice(0, this.columnArray.length);
this.columns.push(this.columnName);}
```

I'm relatively new to Angular & Typescript and I'm having problems getting this sorted out so any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So, let me try to explain. To make your code show the columnName, you just need to change your html like that (your `columnId` won't be working though):

```html
<div *ngFor="let column of columns">
<button class="actionbutton" id="{{columnId}}" (click)="showColumn(selectedColumn)">{{column}}</button></div>
```

That is, because `columns` is just an array of columnNames. In your *ngFor you are iterating through `columns`, so that each `column` is one columnName-string in the end.

Besides that, you have some "not so good" things in your code. Your columns-array should be an array of objects with the parameters `id` and `name`. Then you can change your html to:

```html
<div *ngFor="let column of columns">
<button class="actionbutton" id="{{column.id}}" (click)="showColumn(selectedColumn)">{{column.name}}</button></div>
```

Furthermore `this.columnName` indicates that you are using a global variable that you are overwriting in a loop over and over again... But you will learn step by step :-)

Comment: Tom - thanks so much! I tried your first suggestion and it worked like a champ. Now I'm going to refactor my code to implement the correct approach that you outlined.

Comment: @B.Youngman You're very welcome. Have fun with angular! There are a few great tutorials out there, that teach you the basics.